# Solve $(xp-y)^{2}(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}=a(1+p^2)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question is to solve this differential equation:-
$$(xp-y)^{2}(x^2+y^2)^{-3/2}=a(1+p^2)$$where $$p = \frac{dy}{dx}$$.

Question is given in the clairaut's form in my notebook.
But seems some proper substitution would do the trick .
Hints/leads are appreciated.

Comment: Obviously $y=\pm ix$ are solutions.

Comment: Not so obviously, $x^2+y^2=c^2$ also gives possible solutions. Test with $x=c\sin(t)$, $y=c\cos(t)$, $p=\dot y/\dot x=-\tan(t)$. $$(c\sec(t))^2c^{-3}=a\sec^2(t),$$ thus $ac=1$ is necessary.

Comment: after substitution of x and y , it doesn't get reduced to clairaut's?

Comment: @ Lutz Lehmann. $y=\pm ix$ aren't solutions ? Where did you see written that $y=\pm ix$ are all solutions ?

Comment: @JJacquelin : I'm sorry if that came over otherwise, but these circles are also only some exceptional examples of the solution set. The derivation obviously only makes sense for $c\ne0$. For $c=0$ the equation is singular, one would have to apply some limit to justify that $y=\pm ix $, $p=\pm i$ are in the closure of the set of complex solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to at least get a graphical picture. Transform into polar coordinates $x+iy=e^{iφ}$, and use differentials in a very loose manner, $dx+i\,dy=(dr+ir\,dφ)e^{iφ}$, so that
\begin{align}
(x\,dy-y\,dx)^2r^{-3}&=a(dx^2+dy^2)\tag1
\\
r\,dφ^2&=a(dr^2+r^2dφ^2)\tag2
\\
\frac{r(φ)}{a}-r(φ)^2&=r'(φ)^2 \iff r'(φ)^2+\left(r(φ)-\frac1{2a}\right)^2=\frac1{4a^2} \tag3
\end{align}
Now one can either go the square root way, or go one derivative deeper
$$
\frac{r'(φ)}{a}-2r(φ)r'(φ)^2=2r'(φ)r''(φ)\tag4
$$
so either $r'=0$ via (3) giving the constant solution $r=0$ or the circle $r=\frac1a$; or in the other factor
$$
\frac1{2a}-r=r''.\tag5
$$
This is a harmonic oscillator with solutions
$$
r(φ)=\frac1{2a}+c_1\cosφ+c_2\sinφ\tag6
$$
In view of the second form of (3), this requires $c_1^2+c_2^2=\frac1{4a^2}$ or
$$
r(φ)=\frac1{2a}\left(1+\cos(φ+\psi)\right)\tag7
$$
for some constant phase shift angle $\psi$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y\right)^{2}=a+a\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}\tag 1$$
In polar coordinates
$\begin{cases}
x=r\cos(\varphi)\\
y=r\sin(\varphi)
\end{cases} \quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
dx=\cos(\varphi)dr-r\sin(\varphi)d\varphi\\
dy=\sin(\varphi)dr+r\cos(\varphi)d\varphi
\end{cases}$

Putting them into Eq.$(1)$ and after simplification leads to :
$$\left(\frac{dr}{d\varphi}\right)^2=\frac{r}{a}-r^2 \tag 2$$
Eq.$(2)$ agrees with the equation already found by Lutz Lehmann.
$$d\varphi=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{\frac{r}{a}-r^2}}dr$$
$$\varphi=\pm\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{r}{a}-r^2}}dr=\pm\sin^{-1}(2ar-1)+\text{constant}$$
The inverse function is :
$$\boxed{r(\varphi)=\frac{1}{2a}\left(\pm\sin(\varphi+c)+1 \right)}$$
This is the equation of a set of cardioids.

Back to Cartesian coordinates :
$$2a\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\pm\frac{y\cos(c)+x\sin(c)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+1$$

Comment: Thanks for writing . Mind if i ask how did you see to use polar ? seeing  $(x^2+y^2)$ ?

Comment: In any case, if the solving appears too difficult in Cartesian coordinates it is usual to try in other kind of coordinates. Trying polar coodinates is common. $x^2+y^2$ is a further indication.

Comment: Thanks for writing back. It was helpful.

Comment: Can this be reduced to Clairaut's ? I am asking this because this is given under Clairaut's in my notebook of problems. But this doesn't seem to be reducible to Clairaut's form ..?